# Generating unique HTML ids in Rails when using a repeated partial that has form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, actionview

I have a view on my current project which does something like the following(in haml):

```
-@horses.each do |horse|
  = render :partial => 'main/votingbox', :locals => {:horse => horse}
```

The in the _votingbox.html.haml file I have the following:

```
%div.votingbox
  %span.name= horse.name
  %div.genders
    - if horse.male
      %img{:src => 'images/male.png', :alt => 'Male'} 
    - if horse.female
      %img{:src => 'images/female.png', :alt => 'Female'}
  %div.voting_form
    = form_for(Vote.new, {:url => horse_vote_path(horse)}) do |f|
      = f.label :comment, "Your opinion"
      = f.text_field :comment
      ...
      a bunch of labels and input elements follow generated using the form helpers
```

This will generate working code but it does generate forms with the same ids for all the form elements which makes the HTML invalid once the votingbox partial is rendered a second time.

My first guess at fixing this was to specify a unique :id to form_for but that only applies to the form tag generated by form_for and not any of the tags inside the form_for block.

One definite solution to this problem is to go through and manually define my own unique ids on form_for and all the form elements I use. This is more work than I had hoped for.

Is there an easier or cleaner way to get unique ids in a similar format to the way Rails currently generates them on all my form elements?

Answer (score 2):

*I have removed the original answer as it is totally irrelevant to the updated version of the question.*

**Update:** So now we know that you have an unsaved ActiveRecord object passed to the `form_for` call, the answer becomes simple: You can override any parameter that `form_for` generates. That includes the element id. And `fields_for` sets the context for a specific record.

```
= form_for(Vote.new, :url => horse_vote_path(horse), :id => dom_id(horse, 'vote')) do |f|
  = f.fields_for horse, :index => horse do |fh|
    = fh.text_field :whatever
    …
```

Comment: get_vote in this scenario is always going to return `Vote.new` which will be an unsaved ActiveRecord object. I've revised the original question accordingly.
What would be ideal here is if I could generate the form ids based on the id of the horse object. In this situation the id for the form would be `vote_new_1` for when that partial is rendered for the Horse object with id 1.

Comment: May I suggest: `:id => dom_id(horse, 'vote')` to generetate `horse_123_vote`. It's easier to read.

Comment: This is a good suggestion and is a much cleaner version of my current code. However this still leads to needing to do the following inside that form_for block that would follow: `f.text_field :comment, :id => dom_id(horse, 'vote_comment')`

Comment: I'm not sure this will work fine and I can't try it now but `form_for([horse, Vote.new], :url => horse_vote_path(horse))` may just work. Try it and let me know if it works so I'll update the answer.

Comment: Another thing to try: `form_for(horse.votes.build, :url => horse_vote_path(horse))`. This could work if you have `has_many :votes` in your `Horse` model.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the autogenerated `id`s and `name`s of all `form_for` content with `:as` like the following:

```
= form_for(Vote.new, :as => horse.name, {:url => horse_vote_path(horse)}) do |f|
  = f.label :comment, "Your opinion"
  = f.text_field :comment
```

So if a given `horse.name` is `foobar`, it will generate a comment field whose `id` is `foobar_comment` and name is `foobar[comment]`

But remember to make sure that the dynamic parameter is acceptable as an html id, a `horse.name` like `hor$e` is not acceptable as an html id and therefore might break something.

**P.S:** Sorry for answering very late, but at the time the question was asked, I haven't had learnt anything at all about rails! hope that might help someone out there!